# How to set Spinner in one line with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I want to use `EditText` and `Spinner` together. The `Spinner` should be at the end of EditText and underlined. How can I can set `Spinner`'s underline and `EditText`'s underline in one line?

The following is not whole xml file, but a part:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_currency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            </Spinner>

            <com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/spinner_currency"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/spinner_currency"
                app:fletTextAppearance="@style/FloatLabelEditTextStyle">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                    android:id="@+id/material_edit_text_amount"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:hint="Amount"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:met_helperTextAlwaysShown="true"
                    app:met_helperTextColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                    app:met_iconPadding="0dp"
                    tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
            </com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: create a view with width match_parent and height 1 width with underline color and set it in bottom of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout. As you know, the last object you created in FrameLayout is at the top.

Note: No matter which spinner you use. I like material spinner and I have used it.

this seem like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkvt2.png)
Try like this ;

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/material_edit_text_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:met_helperTextAlwaysShown="true"
        app:met_iconPadding="0dp"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
</com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>

<com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_currency"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/actions">

</com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so easy:)